# Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 13, column 85 (byte 186) after filter {

Tags: logstash-grok

## Below is the code where am getting expected on of # error could some one help me with it

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
        }
    }
```

## Filter part with grok

```
filter {
        if "access_logs" in [tags] 
        {
        grok {
            match => {

> Getting error in thess lines                  "message" => "%{IPORHOST:x_forwarded_for} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})" %{NUMBER:response}"
                }
        }
    }
        if "BPM" in [tags] 
        {
        grok {
            match => {
                        "message" => "%{SYSLOG5424SD:BPM_timestamp} %{BASE16NUM:ThreadID} %{WORD:EventType} %{WORD:ShortName}   %{WORD:MessageIdentifier}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:event}"
                    }
            }
        }
        if "syslog" in [tags]
        {
        grok {
            match => {
                        "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program} (?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

## Below is the output

```
 if [tags] == "access_log"
    {
        output {
        elasticsearch { 
                        hosts => ["10.190.188.174:9200"]
                        index => "access-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" #indices to the output
                    }
                }
        }
else if [tags] == "BPM"
{
    output {
    elasticsearch { 
                    hosts => ["10.190.188.174:9200"]
                    index => "bpm-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                }
        }
}
```

> When i try debugging this using service logstash restart the service wont start

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to escape the `"` in your grokstring.

It should look like this:

```
"message" => "%{IPORHOST:x_forwarded_for} - - \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] \"(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})\\" %{NUMBER:response}"
```

Your output is also wrong. You can't have multiple output blocks. Instead you have one output block and put your `if` in there like this:

```
output {
    if[tags] == "access_log" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.190.188.174:9200"]
            index => "access-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" #indices to the output
        }
    } else if [tags] == "BPM" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["10.190.188.174:9200"]
            index => "bpm-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i have made the changes , so for the indices do i need to have these 2 indices created in filebeat. Since these logs are coming from remote server.

Comment: Do you need to create the `access` index when the tag is there AND the `bpm` index when the tag is there? If so, get rid of the else.